# Move Bundle in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am a symfony noob and I installed FOSUserBundle in the src/ directory of my project and everything was working fine. I wanted to move the bundle to the vendor folder to keep everything tidy but now I am getting the following error below:

**ERROR:**

```
Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in app\AppKernel.php on line 22
```

Is there a file I have to update to make symfony look in the vendor folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't just move files into the `vendor` directory. The `vendor` directory is managed by [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/). The way that you add something to your `vendor` directory is to open the `composer.json` file, and add a line under "requirements" that looks something like this:

`"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master"`

The name on the left comes from the package repository at packagist.org, but the better way to find a little more about how to do this is in their [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)

That should contain everything you need to install it correctly.

Once you get it added, and run `php composer.phar update` from your application directory, Composer will download FOSUserBundle, place it in the vendor directory, and add it to the autoloader's namespace and classmaps.

Comment: I had problems installing composer because I had to install wamp on my computer after symfony2 didn't work on zend server. And composer wouldn't let me select the wamp's installation of PHP. Is there any way to do it without composer?

Comment: Or is it better to leave it in src/ if I dont have composer?

Comment: +1, yes this was the right answer. I was a little bit confuse about this question.

Comment: No - it's better to get composer working. Believe me, you want something managing your dependencies other than a manual process. What exactly isn't working with composer?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I have made a separate question for the composer issue if you would like to take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774404/composer-installation-error