# Composer Installation Error

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two server setups on my local computer one is Zend Server and one is a Wamp because I wanted to start working with Symfony 2 and it would not install on Zend.

When I try to install composer I select the php.exe in my wamp folder but I keep getting this error at the end of the install.

**ERROR:**

```
The php exe you selected does not match the one found in your path.

Selected: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.exe
In Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\php.exe

Remove the following from your System Path Environment variable:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin

Warning: Only do this if you are sure that it will not affect anything else.
```

Comment: Maybe this url will help you with removing Zend Server from the environment variable. http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html You can just uninstall Zend completely.

Comment: As @CharliePrynn said, you should pick a PHP executable (a whole server setup) to use. Either choose WAMP or Zend Server. It looks like you want to use WAMP, so I would go ahead and uninstall Zend Server to see if that corrects your issue.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this but I will give it ago

Answer (score 1):

In my case it is

Composer Installation Error

select where php.exe is located

I solved the issue by using
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.exe

and rerun the 
windowpowershell by typing in start->search (run)
then composer in terminal
need11.com